# How can I retrieve data from spinner and process it?

Tags: android, spinner, settext, onitemselectedlistener

This is the part of my code that went wrong(I omitted all the variable declaration to make it short): I need to create two spinners and retrieve values from them, say value1 and value2. Then I need to calculate something with value1 and value2, and the output should be displayed on the screen. I need this output to be updated whenever I selected a (new) item from the spinner. However, My code doesn't pass the value from the spinner to my java code at all. Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sdpsalary_comp);

    //create a spinner called Spinner1
    Spinner1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    //cities is defined as string-array in XML    
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    value1 = Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

    //create another spinner called Spinner2
    Spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.cities, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    value2 = Spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
}

// I need to update the output field whenever I changed the content from the spinners
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int pos, long id) {
    String output;
    switch(parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            value1 = Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Output = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.out));
            output=Target(base, value1, value2, cost); 
    //variables base, cost and method Target() are defined somewhere else
            Output.setText(output);
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            value2 = Spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Output = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.out));
            output=Target(base, value1, value2, cost); //base and cost are defined somewhere else
            Output.setText(output);
            break;
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

Here is part of my XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="252dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/NewCity"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.272"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/CurrentCity"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.293" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.196"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/NewCity"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.191" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/TargetSalary"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newCity" />
```

This is the logcat after I added spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

```
09-10 00:25:37.938 7797-7797/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.gatech.seclass.sdpsalarycomp, PID: 7797
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.gatech.seclass.sdpsalarycomp/edu.gatech.seclass.sdpsalarycomp.SDPSalaryCompActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:66)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:344)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:783)
    at edu.gatech.seclass.sdpsalarycomp.SDPSalaryCompActivity.onCreate(SDPSalaryCompActivity.java:60)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: are values getting populated in spinner?

Comment: Are you initializing your `Spinner` to the `onItemSelected`? `Spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`

Comment: @SushantSomani Yes, I can click and change values in the spinner from AVD, but that value doesn't pass into my java code.

Comment: @Tepits Did you mean I should add that line of code before or after value1 = Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()? No my app crashes either way.

Comment: @JieyuYou - Initialize it on your `onCreate` after the `findViewById()`.

Comment: @Tepits It still crashes.

Comment: @JieyuYou - can you please share your crash logs?

Comment: @Tepits it is IndexOutOfBoundsException, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your getting of the selected value inside `onItemSelected` like this:

```
// Change this
value1 = Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

// to this
value1 = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));
```

Also the initializing of your `Output` TextView, you can set it on `onCreate`.

```
Output = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.out)); // move this on your onCreate
```

Comment: Still have IndexOutofBoundsException issues

Comment: Remove your `value1 = Spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();` on your `onCreate` method. Because you are not setting any selected item on your `onCreate`.

Comment: You are right, and the reason why my app keeps crashing is because of the initial (default) value of variable "base". After adding an if() statement my app can launch properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please add below lines in `onCreate()` method,

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

without these, spinner cannot listen click event.

Comment: I tried, but it crashes.. IndexOutOfBOundsException

Comment: I just added it

Comment: check R.array.cities if really have items

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of using Spinner in Android

```
         String[] spinnerData=new String["A","B","C"];

            ArrayAdapter<String> itemsArray=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerData);
        Spinner spinner1=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);       
        spinner1.setAdapter(itemsArray);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String selectedItem=String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });

        Spinner spinner2=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);       
        spinner2.setAdapter(itemsArray);

        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String selectedItem=String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you point out my mistake? It will help me a lot.

Comment: @JieyuYou now you have selected value in selectedItem variable. Can you share in which java code you want to pass it?

Comment: No, value1 and value2 remain the same (i.e., the first value from the spinner)

Comment: I've edited my answer, where I've set 2 different setOnItemSelectedListener for both of them. @JieyuYou

Comment: @JieyuYou's implementation is more convenient than this. Just create one function `onItemSelected` for the two spinners, then it will based on their ids.